# how to get the length (count of rows) of this matlab matrix?

Tags: matlab

I'm quite new to matlab and just need to change a very small thing in a code. I have the following matrix:

```
ans =

     1     1     1
     1     2     1
     2     1     1
     2     2     2
```

how to get the count of rows of this ans? it should be 4

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use the [size](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/size.html) function:

```
nRows = size(myMatrix, 1);  % 1 stands for the first dimension
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use the [size](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html) function

```
size(ans, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I find it's much more readable to first define

```
rows = @(x) size(x,1); 
cols = @(x) size(x,2);
```

and then use, for example, like this:

```
for y = 1:rows(myMatrix)
    for x = 1:cols(myMatrix)
        do_whatever(myMatrix(y,x))
    end
end
```

It might appear as a small saving, but `size(.., 1)` must be one of the most commonly used functions.

(By the way, looping over a matrix like this might not be the best choice for performance-critical code. But if that's not an issue, then go for the most readable choice.)

Answer (score 2):

Also you can get both rows and columns count using one call:

```
[rows columns] = size(myMatrix);
```

Answer (score 1):

To count number of rows in a matrix:

```
 length(ans)
```

gives the maximum dimension of a matrix.  For a 2 dimensional matrix, it is the larger of the number of rows and columns.  I had read in a tutorial that length gives the first non-singleton dimension, but this is incorrect according to the official MathWorks MATLAB documentation and appears to be the cause of a bug in a program that I am using.